# ANCOVA Supressor effect?

Tags: interpretation, ancova, suppressor

I'm having a wierd kind of effect I don't fully understand when running an ANCOVA analysis. To keep it simple I have a variable X and a variable Y, these variables are significantly correlated to eachother.

When I put both of them in the ANCOVA (x as fixed since it's categorical and y as covariate since it's a continious variable) neither of them are significant. When I put variable X in the analysis without variabel Y variable X is not signifcant. When I put variable Y in the analysis without variable x variable Y IS significant.

Am I dealing with a supressor effect here, and is that even possible in an ANCOVA? (I've only seen these kind of effects in regression analysis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have a suppressor effect. You have the opposite of a suppressor effect. While the name may not be intuitive, a variable acts as a suppressor when it **strengthens** an effect when it is included in the model. One version of a suppressor variable is one that is uncorrelated with the other independent variable, but highly correlated with the dependent variable. When included in the model, the suppressor variable will explain a lot of variance, reducing the residual. However, it will not share much variance with the independent variable. Thus, the numerator sum of squares is the same for your IV of interest, but the denominator sum of squares is much lower. This makes your F value larger and subsequently your p value smaller.

What you have is likely a confounding variable. When two independent variables are correlated, some of the variance they account for is shared. For instance imagine you had a group of boys and girls, and you are studying their heights. All the boys are 5 years old and all the girls are 6 years old. Sex and age are perfectly correlated, so any difference in height if you do ANCOVA or any other kind of general linear model (GLM) on them you wouldn't be able to tell of differences were due to age or sex. If you were interested in sex differences, you would say that age is confounded with sex in your study (hence confounding variable). Separately, height is surely related to sex. Height is surely related to age. Together in the same model, there will be no effect. This is a somewhat poor example, because when two IVs are perfectly correlated (or colinear), there is no basis for assigning variance to either of them and the model is not identifiable. That's a statistical problem though. The qualitative aspect of the example holds.

The statistical reason for this is that GLM's (i.e. regression, and I should add since you seem to be unaware in your question, ANOVA and ANCOVA are special cases of regression and are not entirely different kinds of analysis) give you marginal effects. A marginal effect is the effect controlling for any other effects in the model. Put a different way, it will hold constant the value of other variables in the model. That way if you had all different ages of boys and girls you can can say something like, "On average across a sample of ages, boys are taller than girls." Which is another way of saying, "The effect of sex on height cannot be accounted for solely by age." ANCOVA is a modification of the GLM, but the details may not be important for your question. One difference is that all shared variance is "given" to the covariate. Thus, for covariate the results should not be the marginal effect, but is instead just the correlation of covariate and the DV. Your IV will be the marginal effect though.

In sum, your IV is likely confounded with your covariate. While your IV is related to the DV, it is also related to you covariate. Statistically, you can't tell if the change in the DV is attributable to the IV or the covariate. Another possibility is you have mediation relationship. If your IV was manipulated, and you measured your covariate after your manipulation, and ideally before your DV, and several other assumption you can read about in Baron and Kenny or Zhao, Lynch and Chen rather than being confounded you can say that your continuous variable mediates the relationship between your IV and your DV. Mediation would be your IV causes an effect on the covariate, which in turn causes an effect on the DV. You really shouldn't be doing this with ANCOVA though, since you are interested in the effects of both the IV and the covariate. You'd use regression models to do all the necessary models to show mediation.

Zhao, X., Lynch, J. G., & Chen, Q. (2010). Reconsidering Baron and Kenny: Myths and truths about mediation analysis. Journal of consumer research, 37(2), 197-206.

Baron, R. M., & Kenny, D. A. (1986). The moderator–mediator variable distinction in social psychological research: Conceptual, strategic, and statistical considerations. Journal of personality and social psychology, 51(6), 1173.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, helps alot.. (its for my thesis)

Answer (score 0):

ANOVA (or ANCOVA) significance is dependent (conditional) on what is in the model. So when you have both X and Y in the model as predictors and then you would say given that X is in the model then Y is not significant or given than Y is in the model the response does not vary over levels of X. So say you have X and Y in the model and Y was significant then you can't just assume that a model with only Y in it will result in Y being significant.